# Update recyclerview in android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created a simple note app. Tried several ways but could not update recycler view dynamically(without swipe)

> **CustomAdpater Class**
>
> > I used a method setValues in adapter class which is called in main activity to update data but it's not working. There is another activity for adding data into database

```
public class CustomAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Model> models;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> models){
        this.context = context;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.string_text.setText(models.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getText());
        holder.time_text.setText(models.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getNotes());
        holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotesDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return models.size(); }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView string_text, time_text;
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            string_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            time_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeshow);
            constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
        }
    }

    public void setValues(ArrayList<Model> models){
        this.models = models;
    }
}
```

> **Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper db;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    ArrayList<Model> models;

    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        models = new ArrayList<>();

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, models);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addData();
            }
        });

        displayData();

    }

    private void addData() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataAdd.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    void displayData() {
        Cursor cursor = db.viewData();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            Model model = new Model(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
            models.add(model);
            customAdapter.setValues(models);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use MVVM, LiveData can solve your problem.

Comment: You need a way to know when the DB gets updated by another activity, possibly a callback or listener, only then you can populate the adapter. If you use MVVM architecture, the LiveData and ViewModel will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to work, because you can't add to recycler view data from SQLite(i suggest) directly without refreshing the whole app.

Android devs recommend to use Android Room instead of pure SQLite API:

> Caution: Although these APIs are powerful, they are fairly low-level
> and require a great deal of time and effort to use:
>
> There is no compile-time verification of raw SQL queries. As your data graph changes, you need to update the affected SQL queries
> manually. This process can be time consuming and error prone.
> You need to use lots of boilerplate code to convert between SQL queries and data objects.
>
> For these reasons, we highly recommended using the Room Persistence
> Library as an abstraction layer for accessing information in your
> app's SQLite databases.

However, you can use Use Android Room (abstract layer of SQLite) with MVVM pattern - it would work with data and you will able to add data to RecyclerView dynamically (LiveData).
Read android devs tutorial about [MVVM, LiveData, and Room](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0), it's relatively simple.

You will need to create : Data entity (your table items), DAO interface, Database itself (without manually writing bulky stuff), Repository (mediator between DAO and ViewModel), and ViewModel (who will track your data and keep it through the lifecycle, then connect it to recycler view.

For further reading

- [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)
- [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)
- [Migrate from SQLite to Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/sqlite-room-migration)
- [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture)